# TensorFlow Lite: Update existing model or add new one in deployed app

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I'm creating a mobile app (with Flutter, for more details) that will need to do some offline inference using TensorFlow Lite models. The fact this needs to be offline means the models need to be shipped with the APP.

I know how to deploy the models with the APP (see [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/working-with-tensorflow-lite-in-flutter-f00d733a09c3), for example; there are plenty out there) but, as these might change over time - for example re-trained for better accuracy with new data or even new models added to analyse different things - it will be good to find a way of doing that without the need to update the whole application.

So far, the only options I have found for the dynamic update/addition of models require the APP connecting to an external service hosting the models, like Firebase, but that's not good enough when the APP needs to run offline.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Many thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but are you saying you want to update the app (one part of the app) without internet connection (or network connection)? The act of updating the app from the Play Store/ App Store requires an internet connection.

- **Manually install new application updates.** This would be updating the entire app, not just the model file, but this is fine, you just don't have to make any code changes.

  - On Android: Install a new APK `adb install`, and
  - On iOS: use Adhoc distribution
- **Model file picker and manual model selection:** Alternatively, you can add a file picker in the application to select a local model file. This model file will need to be on the device, which you can copy onto the device manually (e.g. `adb push model.tflite` on Android, Airdrop on iOS).
- **Local network hosted model:** Or you can download the model from the local network automatically (still "offline"/ no internet connection).

Comment: No, no. For updating the app - or the model - it is fine to have internet connection. What I don’t want is to need internet connection for using the app. Updating the whole app when there is a change in one model is what I want to avoid: I want to keep the models in the device such that they can be updated (or new ones added) independently. I’ll investigate the second and third options you suggest and see how to select a model file dynamically.

Comment: It sounds like you should bundle all the models with your application then, and switch between them. Then you can have your logic to switch between them. You would have to code this in advance.